# How to insert data from client to backend using express and mysql?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js

I have an issue posting data to backend, I am using angularJs on client side Problem is i am getting data from the client as you can see  `console.log(post)` is printing values from the angular factory, But i am getting below error. I am new to express and mysql dotn know how to fix this issue any help will be appreciated.

app.js

```
app.post("/test/create", function(req,res) {
    var post = {
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        address: req.body.address
    };
    console.log("got data from client",post);
    connection.query('INSERT INTO worker_table SET ?', post, function(error) {

        if (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        } else {
            console.log('success');    
        }
        connection.end();
    });
});
```

error

```
got data from client { firstName: 'dasd', lastName: 'dad', address: 'dad' }
Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Cannot enqueue Quit after invoking quit.
    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/Users/syedhussain/Project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:202:16)
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/syedhussain/Project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:13)
    at Protocol.quit (/Users/syedhussain/Project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:88:23)
    at Connection.end (/Users/syedhussain/Project/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:242:18)
    at Query._callback (/Users/syedhussain/Project/app.js:55:20)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/syedhussain/Project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at /Users/syedhussain/Project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:226:14
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:417:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:346:13)
```

Comment: remove connection.end(), then check, is it ok?

Comment: If i remove connection.end() I don't see big stack of errors but i see the error " Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit."

Comment: I used once Mysql with Nodejs , i got this error , i was quitting connection on every request, when i removed it, it works fine. basically you got connection when your app start, if you quit the connection, query will not be in queue.

Comment: Thanks for the help!